# nextjs13 initializing state with localStorage data

Tags: next.js13

I'm trying to initialize a `todos` state with `localStorage` data in nextjs13 (app directory).
Using the dev server it renders it fine and shows the correct html but there is an error in the server:

```
- error src\components\TodoApp.js (15:19) @ localStorage
- error ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at TodoApp (./src/components/TodoApp.js:20:90)
  13 | 
  14 |     const [todos, setTodos] = useState(
> 15 |         JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || []
     |                   ^
  16 |     );
  17 | 
  18 |     useEffect(() => {
```

Even though working in the dev server with the error, when I build it, it fails with the same error but this time it doesn't work. `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

I am using a client component "use client" on the top, doesn't this mean it will render in the client where localStorage is defined?

I'm trying to use this method and not the method that is commented out in the code below (empty array state and using useEffect to add localStorage data), because it does a little flash (does a second render when adding the localStorage data I guess).

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TodoForm from "./TodoForm";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

export default function TodoApp() {
    // const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     setTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || []);
    // }, []);

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || []
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    }, [todos]);

    return (
        <div>
            <TodoForm todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
            <TodoList todos={todos} />
        </div>
    );
}
```